# How to write Superexponents

Tags: errors, superscripts

How do I write stacked up exponents? For example, I tried doing `$2^2^65533$` and it yelled at me :(

I know about `\uparrow` but it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: You should try `$2^{2^{65533}}$`

Comment: Do you want maximum 2 exponent tiers, or are you seeking an arbitrary number (continued exponents?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you nest several super/subscripts, you should disambiguate the writing since it is not clear (for LaTeX) if you want to write `(2^2)^65533` or `2^(2^65533)`. 
You should therefor use curly brackets around the argument of the power function for having an unequivocal notation.

In your case, you should write `$2^{2^{65533}}$`

[image]

---

<sub><s>(note that `$2^{2^65533}$` is also ok, since it is already unequivocal)</s></sub>

The right use of the exponent function is `^{<argument>}` (e.g. `$e^{i\pi}$`). 
However, if your argument is one character-long only, you can use the shorthand `^<argument>` (i.e. without curly brackets, e.g. `$2^4$`). Thus, you *cannot* write `$2^{2^65533}$`, even if it's mathematically unequivocal.

Comment: `$2^{2^65533}$` is not the same as `$2^{2^{65533}}$`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer thanks for noticing. I've edited my answer

Answer (score 7):

The LaTeX manual always shows the syntax

```
<base>^{<exponent>}
```

You should type

```
10^{2}  e^{x}  e^{-x^2}  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!}
```

If you *always* do like this, your input would be

```
2^{2^{65533}}
```

---

If you type `2^3^4`, you get the `double exponent` error message, because the input is ambiguous. Other software might accept it, usually interpreting it as if it were `2^81`, but TeX is a *typesetting* system, so it wants you to be clear about your intentions.

Most importantly, `2^81` would be ambiguous as well, again because TeX is a typesetting system and cannot distinguish `2^8x` and `2^8 x`.

CAS software might be able to interpret `2^8x` as “x multiplied by 256”, TeX does *not* interpret anything because it doesn't do math.

If you want “2 to the exponent 8x”, type `2^{8x}`; if you want “256 times x”, type `2^{8}x`.